# How to Troubleshoot the error :A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment"?

Tags: python, java, html, flask, pycharm

Hello everyone and thank you for reading.
I have the following error while running my program and can't figure out what the solution would be. I also looked at all the topics with a similar error here, but could not resolve my issue. Here the error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001a9683664, pid=1214, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.6+10-829.5-jcef (17.0.6+10) (build 17.0.6+10-b829.5)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-17.0.6+10-829.5-jcef (17.0.6+10-b829.5, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [HIToolbox+0x1d6664]  NotifyItemSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*)+0x1c
```

My program is a 100 days of code, Python Pro Bootcamp project where I'm working on creating a simple drop down menu where I rate the quality of a coffee shop and add it to a database of coffee shops to work from. My project has been crashing regularly. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here is the code, that I'm executing in Pycharm:

Here the logfile of the error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001a9683664, pid=1214, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.6+10-829.5-jcef (17.0.6+10) (build 17.0.6+10-b829.5)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-17.0.6+10-829.5-jcef (17.0.6+10-b829.5, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [HIToolbox+0x1d6664]  NotifyItemSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*)+0x1c
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JBR
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/carlosperalta/java_error_in_pycharm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/carlosperalta/java_error_in_pycharm.hprof -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot,trieDescend -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Dsun.java2d.metal=true -Djbr.catch.SIGABRT=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Xmx1024m -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Users/carlosperalta/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.1/pycharm.vmoptions --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/com.apple.eawt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/com.apple.eawt.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/com.apple.laf=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.dnd.peer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.java2d=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.lwawt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi=ALL-UNNAMED -Djna.boot.library.path=/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/lib/jna/aarch64 -Dpty4j.preferred.native.folder=/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/lib/pty4j -Dsplash=true -Didea.home.path=/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents -Didea.executable=pycharm -Djava.system.class.loader=com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader -Djna.noclasspath=true -Djna.nosys=true -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharmCE2023.1 -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains 

Host: "Mac14,7" arm64, 8 cores, 8G, Darwin 22.1.0, macOS 13.0 (22A380)
Time: Fri Apr 14 13:19:53 2023 EDT elapsed time: 165.014992 seconds (0d 0h 2m 45s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000011983ae00):  JavaThread "AWT-AppKit" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=259, stack(0x000000016cfb8000,0x000000016d7b4000)]

Stack: [0x000000016cfb8000,0x000000016d7b4000],  sp=0x000000016d7ab290,  free space=8140k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [HIToolbox+0x1d6664]  NotifyItemSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*)+0x1c
C  [HIToolbox+0x1d62e4]  SelectItemAndRestoreAllMenuBits(MenuSelectData&, SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*)+0x48c
C  [HIToolbox+0x873bc]  SimulateSelection(unsigned char, unsigned char, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*, unsigned int*)+0x5fc
C  [HIToolbox+0x1d2374]  SimulateMenuSelectionWithOptions(MenuData*, OpaqueMenuRef*, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned char)+0xd0
C  [Shortcut+0xc698]  -[SCTMenuItemGRL perform]+0x130
C  [Shortcut+0xc204]  -[SCTSearchManager doPerformResource:]+0x24
C  [Foundation+0x7a090]  __NSFireDelayedPerform+0x174
C  [CoreFoundation+0x9b578]  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__+0x20
C  [CoreFoundation+0x9b220]  __CFRunLoopDoTimer+0x3ac
C  [CoreFoundation+0x9ad78]  __CFRunLoopDoTimers+0x164
C  [CoreFoundation+0x80760]  __CFRunLoopRun+0x768
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7f8a4]  CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x264
C  [HIToolbox+0x323bc]  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode+0x124
C  [HIToolbox+0x3204c]  ReceiveNextEventCommon+0xec
C  [HIToolbox+0x31f48]  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter+0x48
C  [AppKit+0x39630]  _DPSNextEvent+0x278
C  [AppKit+0x387c0]  -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x2d8
C  [libosxapp.dylib+0x36e8]  -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0xf0
C  [libawt_lwawt.dylib+0x86f60]  Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_LWCToolkit_doAWTRunLoopImpl+0x1e8
j  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.doAWTRunLoopImpl(JZZI)Z+0 java.desktop
j  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.doAWTRunLoop(JZI)Z+6 java.desktop
j  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.invokeAndWait(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/awt/Component;ZI)V+301 java.desktop
j  jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+145 java.base@17.0.6
J 36866 c2 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@17.0.6 (65 bytes) @ 0x000000014916b04c [0x000000014916adc0+0x000000000000028c]
j  com.intellij.ui.mac.screenmenu.Menu.invokeWithLWCToolkit(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+78
j  com.intellij.ui.mac.screenmenu.Menu.invokeMenuClosing()V+45
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4583b0]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, JavaThread*)+0x38c
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4b1634]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, JavaThread*)+0x31c
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4b5c8c]  jni_CallVoidMethod+0x138
C  [libmacscreenmenu64.dylib+0x6f28]  -[Menu menuDidClose:]+0x138
C  [AppKit+0x335908]  -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCloseEvent:handlerCallRef:]+0x58
C  [AppKit+0x296dec]  NSSLMMenuEventHandler+0x390
C  [HIToolbox+0xa944]  DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x444
C  [HIToolbox+0x9dc4]  SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x164
C  [HIToolbox+0x9c54]  SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions+0x2c
C  [HIToolbox+0x9e550]  SendMenuClosed(MenuData*, unsigned int, unsigned char)+0xd4
C  [HIToolbox+0x9e304]  HideMenus(MenuSelectData*, __CFArray*)+0x80
C  [HIToolbox+0x6f304]  CancelMenuTracking+0xd8
C  [Shortcut+0xc02c]  -[SCTSearchManager hideSearchWindow]+0x28
C  [Shortcut+0x9e50]  -[SCTSearchManager control:textView:doCommandBySelector:]+0x274
C  [AppKit+0x29a708]  -[NSTextView doCommandBySelector:]+0x8c
C  [AppKit+0x29a63c]  -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) doCommandBySelector:completionHandler:]+0xe4
C  [AppKit+0x1e83dc]  -[NSKeyBindingManager(NSKeyBindingManager_MultiClients) interpretEventAsCommand:forClient:]+0x608
C  [AppKit+0x1efd14]  __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_5+0x168
C  [AppKit+0x940c8c]  __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3.657+0x64
C  [AppKit+0x1efb68]  -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:]+0x94
C  [AppKit+0x940bec]  __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.654+0x13c
C  [HIToolbox+0x6c58c]  __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_5+0x60
C  [HIToolbox+0x7ceb8]  invocation function for block in DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x94
C  [AppKit+0x93be88]  __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.180+0x244
C  [AppKit+0x1ea294]  __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2+0x64
C  [AppKit+0x1ea1e0]  -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:]+0x94
C  [AppKit+0x1e9754]  -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]+0x7ec
C  [AppKit+0x1e8efc]  _NSTSMEventHandler+0x14c
C  [HIToolbox+0xa944]  DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x444
C  [HIToolbox+0x9dc4]  SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x164
C  [HIToolbox+0x9c54]  SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions+0x2c
C  [HIToolbox+0x68a28]  SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler+0x1b0
C  [HIToolbox+0x68f78]  __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke+0x1c8
C  [HIToolbox+0x68d84]  __SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke+0xe4
C  [HIToolbox+0x68a80]  SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler+0x208
C  [HIToolbox+0x68830]  SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler+0x104
C  [HIToolbox+0x68458]  SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler+0x128
C  [HIToolbox+0x681e4]  __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2+0x140
C  [HIToolbox+0x67f68]  __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke+0x11c
C  [HIToolbox+0x67dec]  TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler+0x270
C  [HIToolbox+0x67b6c]  __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_4+0x140
C  [HIToolbox+0x6797c]  __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3+0x15c
C  [HIToolbox+0x6765c]  __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2+0x138
C  [HIToolbox+0x67368]  __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke+0x138
C  [HIToolbox+0x54ea0]  TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler+0x900
C  [AppKit+0x940aa0]  __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3.650+0x94
C  [AppKit+0x94077c]  __204-[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:]_block_invoke.632+0xc0
C  [AppKit+0x1e7c80]  -[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:]+0x150
C  [AppKit+0x1e7694]  -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]+0x588
C  [AppKit+0x1e70cc]  -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:allowingSyntheticEvent:]+0x84
C  [AppKit+0x1e6f24]  -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:]+0x9c
C  [AppKit+0x1e6d78]  -[NSTextView keyDown:]+0x20c
C  [AppKit+0x16755c]  -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:]+0x142c
C  [AppKit+0x165f5c]  -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:]+0x11c
C  [AppKit+0x5b0594]  -[NSMenuWindowManagerWindow _handleKeyEvent:]+0xac
C  [AppKit+0x88c440]  NSMenuWindowManagerMenuItemCarbonEventHandler+0x134
C  [HIToolbox+0xa944]  DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x444
C  [HIToolbox+0x9dc4]  SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x164
C  [HIToolbox+0x9c54]  SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions+0x2c
C  [HIToolbox+0x4a0c8]  ToolboxEventDispatcherHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)+0x4b8
C  [HIToolbox+0xadec]  DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x8ec
C  [HIToolbox+0x9dc4]  SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*)+0x164
C  [HIToolbox+0x1ffd4]  SendEventToEventTarget+0x28
C  [HIToolbox+0x9a2c0]  IsUserStillTracking(MenuSelectData*, unsigned char*)+0x16b4
C  [HIToolbox+0x1d6e5c]  TrackMenuCommon(MenuSelectData&, unsigned char*, SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*)+0x574
C  [HIToolbox+0xa458c]  MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned int, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*)+0x15c
C  [HIToolbox+0xa4380]  _HandleMenuSelection2+0x1a0
C  [AppKit+0x18c0f4]  _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent+0x100
C  [AppKit+0x18bf18]  _DPSEventHandledByCarbon+0x3c
C  [AppKit+0x38db8]  -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x8d0
C  [libosxapp.dylib+0x36e8]  -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0xf0
C  [AppKit+0x2cbf0]  -[NSApplication run]+0x1d0
C  [libosxapp.dylib+0x3440]  +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:]+0xd0
...<more frames>...

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.doAWTRunLoopImpl(JZZI)Z+0 java.desktop
j  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.doAWTRunLoop(JZI)Z+6 java.desktop
j  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.invokeAndWait(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/awt/Component;ZI)V+301 java.desktop
j  jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+145 java.base@17.0.6
J 36866 c2 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@17.0.6 (65 bytes) @ 0x000000014916b04c [0x000000014916adc0+0x000000000000028c]
j  com.intellij.ui.mac.screenmenu.Menu.invokeWithLWCToolkit(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+78
j  com.intellij.ui.mac.screenmenu.Menu.invokeMenuClosing()V+45
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Register to memory mapping:

 x0=0x0 is NULL
 x1=0x0 is NULL
 x2=0x0 is NULL
 x3=0x0000600003942c40 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000e0244a9f2c40 | 40 2c 9f 4a 24 e0 00 00
 x4=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
 x5=0x0000000000000960 is an unknown value
 x6=0x000060000054bda0 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000e024495fbda0 | a0 bd 5f 49 24 e0 00 00
 x7=0x000000016d7ab27c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000011983ae00
 x8=0x9e51358191f80004 is an unknown value
 x9=0x9e51358191f80004 is an unknown value
x10=0x0000000000000dc0 is an unknown value
x11=0x00000000000007fb is an unknown value
x12=0x00000000faa43036 is an unknown value
x13=0x00000000000007fd is an unknown value
x14=0x00000000fac43838 is an unknown value
x15=0x00000000faa43036 is an unknown value
x16=0x0000000000000038 is an unknown value
x17=0x000000007ac00000 is an unknown value
x18=0x0 is NULL
x19=0x0 is NULL
x20=0x0 is NULL
x21=0x0 is NULL
x22=0x000000016d7ab2e8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000011983ae00
x23=0x0 is NULL
x24=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
x25=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
x26=0x0000000379b12fc0 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00000001fd3fdb70 | 70 db 3f fd 01 00 00 00
x27=0x0000000000010001 is an unknown value
x28=0x0000000379b12fc0 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00000001fd3fdb70 | 70 db 3f fd 01 00 00 00


Registers:
 x0=0x0000000000000000  x1=0x0000000000000000  x2=0x0000000000000000  x3=0x0000600003942c40
 x4=0x0000000000000004  x5=0x0000000000000960  x6=0x000060000054bda0  x7=0x000000016d7ab27c
 x8=0x9e51358191f80004  x9=0x9e51358191f80004 x10=0x0000000000000dc0 x11=0x00000000000007fb
x12=0x00000000faa43036 x13=0x00000000000007fd x14=0x00000000fac43838 x15=0x00000000faa43036
x16=0x0000000000000038 x17=0x000000007ac00000 x18=0x0000000000000000 x19=0x0000000000000000
x20=0x0000000000000000 x21=0x0000000000000000 x22=0x000000016d7ab2e8 x23=0x0000000000000000
x24=0x0000000000000001 x25=0x0000000000000001 x26=0x0000000379b12fc0 x27=0x0000000000010001
x28=0x0000000379b12fc0  fp=0x000000016d7ab2c0  lr=0x3d570001a96832e4  sp=0x000000016d7ab290
pc=0x00000001a9683664 cpsr=0x0000000060001000
Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000016d7ab290)
0x000000016d7ab290:   000000016d7ab2c0 1e620001a94f9e40
0x000000016d7ab2a0:   000000016d7ab2e8 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab2b0:   000000016d7b1f58 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab2c0:   000000016d7ab350 3d570001a96832e4
0x000000016d7ab2d0:   0000000379b12fc0 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab2e0:   0000000000000000 0000600001194dc0
0x000000016d7ab2f0:   0000000000000000 0000000379b12fc0
0x000000016d7ab300:   0000000379b12fc0 0000000000010001
0x000000016d7ab310:   0000000379b12fc0 0000000000000001
0x000000016d7ab320:   0000000000000001 0000000379b12fc0
0x000000016d7ab330:   000000011863f7c0 0000000000000022
0x000000016d7ab340:   00000001f90cb000 0000000000000022
0x000000016d7ab350:   000000016d7ab460 934e0001a95343bc
0x000000016d7ab360:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab370:   0000600000127840 0000000118745b00
0x000000016d7ab380:   000000000000000b 000000006d61676e
0x000000016d7ab390:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab3a0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab3b0:   000000006d7ab410 000000011863f7c0
0x000000016d7ab3c0:   0000000379b12fc0 0001000100000000
0x000000016d7ab3d0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab3e0:   0000000000000000 0000000379b12fc0
0x000000016d7ab3f0:   0000000300220000 0000000000000022
0x000000016d7ab400:   0000000000000022 000000011863f7c0
0x000000016d7ab410:   00000001fc425218 ffffffffffffffff
0x000000016d7ab420:   0000600000127840 00000001fc2ffc30
0x000000016d7ab430:   00000001fc2ffc30 00000001f90cb000
0x000000016d7ab440:   000000011863f7c0 0000000379b12fc0
0x000000016d7ab450:   0000000000000022 0000000000000000
0x000000016d7ab460:   000000016d7ab4a0 d6348001a967f374
0x000000016d7ab470:   00000001fc2ffc30 0000000000000040
0x000000016d7ab480:   0000600000453600 000060000051d300 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000001a9683664)
0x00000001a9683564:   d503237f a9bd57f6 a9014ff4 a9027bfd
0x00000001a9683574:   910083fd aa0103f3 aa0103e0 9403e43e
0x00000001a9683584:   f100041f 5400014b aa0003f4 d2800015
0x00000001a9683594:   aa1303e0 aa1503e1 9403e447 97f9be2e
0x00000001a96835a4:   910006b5 eb15029f 54ffff41 aa1303e0
0x00000001a96835b4:   a9427bfd a9414ff4 a8c357f6 d50323ff
0x00000001a96835c4:   ca1e07d0 b6f00050 d4388e20 1403e6ee
0x00000001a96835d4:   d503237f a9be4ff4 a9017bfd 910043fd
0x00000001a96835e4:   d027d248 39645109 f027d234 37000249
0x00000001a96835f4:   52800029 39245109 b027d228 f947fd00
0x00000001a9683604:   94057447 aa0003f3 f029ec62 9108c042
0x00000001a9683614:   94056d3b b4000100 f029ec62 9108c042
0x00000001a9683624:   aa1303e0 9405698e f100041f 54000048
0x00000001a9683634:   f9050280 f9450280 a9417bfd a8c24ff4
0x00000001a9683644:   d65f0fff d503237f d10103ff a9024ff4
0x00000001a9683654:   a9037bfd 9100c3fd aa0103f4 aa0003f3
0x00000001a9683664:   f9400020 94000db7 f9000fe0 79401688
0x00000001a9683674:   79002fe8 b4000640 f90007ff 2f00e400
0x00000001a9683684:   910023e4 d2800000 528dcea1 72adaca1
0x00000001a9683694:   52801922 52800003 97f8ba3c 35000500
0x00000001a96836a4:   f94007e0 910063e4 5285a5a1 72a5a5a1
0x00000001a96836b4:   528dcea2 72adaca2 52800103 97f8c53f
0x00000001a96836c4:   f94007e0 91005be4 528cada1 72ad2e81
0x00000001a96836d4:   528c8f02 72adad22 52800043 97f8c537
0x00000001a96836e4:   f94007f4 f9400fe0 97f8e1f9 aa0003e1
0x00000001a96836f4:   aa1403e0 97f9262d 350001e0 f8020e7f
0x00000001a9683704:   f94007e0 528e4c81 72aeae61 528e8f22
0x00000001a9683714:   72ac6cc2 d2800003 52800104 d2800005
0x00000001a9683724:   aa1303e6 97f8c313 f9400260 b4000040
0x00000001a9683734:   9403e699 f94007e0 97f8c6fe a9437bfd
0x00000001a9683744:   a9424ff4 910103ff d65f0fff d503237f
0x00000001a9683754:   a9be4ff4 a9017bfd 910043fd aa0103f3 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x000000016d7ab2c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000011983ae00
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x1e620001a94f9e40: RemoveEventLoopTimer+0x78 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox at 0x00000001a94ad000
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x000000016d7ab2e8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000011983ae00
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x000000016d7b1f58 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000011983ae00
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x000000016d7ab350 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000011983ae00
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x3d570001a96832e4: _ZL31SelectItemAndRestoreAllMenuBitsR14MenuSelectDataP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS4_+0x48c in /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox at 0x00000001a94ad000




com.intellij.diagnostic.JBRCrash
```

I can include my Pycharm and HTML code if it helps solving the matter.
Thank you!

Comment: *The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.* is telling you what the problem is. Try tweaking the JRE version up, and if not, incrementally down

Comment: I'm afraid I'm new to coding (I've been coding for about a year). What do you mean by "Tweaking the JRE version up"?  What do I need to do?

Comment: Try to download one with a higher version number

Comment: Thanks, looks like I didn't have java installed.

Comment: You did ;) It tells you so